# hostapd how to reduce memory usage

Tags: linux, memory, config, access-point, hostapd

this is my **hostapd.conf** file:

```
interface=wlan0
driver=nl80211
hw_mode=g
ieee80211n=1
channel=6
country_code=US
ieee80211d=1
ssid=MySuperWiFiNetwork
```

Is there any way to configure this file for lower memory usage? It's running on small embedded system. I need an access point that is as simple as possible. Each KB of operating memory is really valuable (now *hostapd* process uses ~1,3 MB).

Maybe exists a 'light' alternative to hostapd? Any suggestions?

Thanks in advance